# UISearchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar positions the search bar in the middle of the window

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to use the `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` property in the iOS7 `UISearchDisplayController` class to display the search bar inside a navigation bar.

Using the [AdvancedTableSearch example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AdvancedTableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) as a base, I've changed the code to disable scopes (which are not allowed in the navigation bar) and set `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` to true, like so.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   // create a mutable array to contain products for the search results table
   self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.products count]];
   self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
}
```

Unfortunately the result I am getting looks like this:

[image: search bar in the wrong place]

The search bar appears in the middle of the screen instead of in the navigationItem.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm not sure if it's related, but `self.searchDisplayController.navigationItem` property is `nil`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the search bar from the table view. Using `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` means that UISearchDisplayController will take care of placing the search bar in the hierarchy for you.

Also, `navigationItem` will be nil until `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` is set to YES. The item is created only when needed.

Comment: Sounds like a big refactoring, right? Will the app still compatible with iOS6 after that?

Comment: No, by using `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` your app can only target iOS 7.

Comment: @NLemay, if you test for iOS7 at runtime, and conditionally set `displaysSearchBarInNavigatorBar` only for iOS7 and up, it gracefully falls back to displaying the searchbar below the navigation bar in iOS6.

Comment: Ok thanks. So all I have to do is to delete the UISearchBar from the UITableView when I detect iOS 7, and set displaysSearchBarInNavigatorBar to true, and it will work? Nothing else to do for iOS 6 compatibility?

Comment: That last sentence is key. `navigationItem` is nil in iOS7 until `displaysSearchBarinNavigationBar` is YES. I was putting a custom left bar button which wouldn't show up in iOS7 (but did in iOS6) and had to place it after putting the searchbar in navbar.

Answer (score 3):

**I was having the same problem as you were and spent hours looking for a solution.** Ultimately I went with creating the `UISearchDisplayController` programatically.

I create a `SearchTableViewController` in the `Storyboard` and then do the rest of the work programatically. The controllers delegate must be included in the header, as you will notice in the code provided below. Now the interesting thing happens when I create the `searchBar`. Notice how I never set its delegate? The `UISearchDisplayController` is doing that for me when I create it with the `searchBar`. Then I only need to set the delegate and source for the `UISearchDislpayController` and for the `searchResults`; which I do right after creating the controller. I cannot provide you with the answer as to "WHY" the `searchBar` gets centered in the view when created in the `Storyboard` and set to `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES` in code, but I had the same problem and found the following to be a viable solution. Especially considering I never have to size anything :)

**SearchTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchableTableViewController : UITableViewController<UISearchDisplayDelegate>
//I only need the SearchDisplayController Delegate because it magically has all the needed child delegates. :)
@end
```

**SearchTableViewController.m**

```
#import "SearchDisplayController.h"

@property (strong,nonatomic)  IBOutlet UITableView *acSearchTableView;
@property (retain,nonatomic)  UISearchBar *acSearchBar;
@property (retain,nonatomic)  UISearchDisplayController *searchDsplyCntrl;
@property (strong,nonatomic)  NSArray *unfilteredResults;
@property (strong,nonatomic)  NSMutableArray *filteredResults;

@implementation SearchTableViewController 

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _acSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
    _acSearchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

    /* NOTE: by default the placholer is centered. It can be left aligned with spaces */
    _acSearchBar.placeholder = @"Search                                                      ";

    _searchDsplyCntrl = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:_acSearchBar contentsController:self];
    _searchDsplyCntrl.delegate = self;
    _searchDsplyCntrl.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    _searchDsplyCntrl.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    _searchDsplyCntrl.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;

    _unfilteredResults = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                                               [ResultObj resultWithName:@"first"],
                                               [ResultObj resultWithName:@"second"],
                                               [ResultObj resultWithName:@"third"],
                                               [ResultObj resultWithName:@"forth"],
                                               [ResultObj resultWithName:@"fifth"],
                                               [ResultObj resultWithName:@"sixth"],
                                               [ResultObj resultWithName:@"seventh"],
                                               [ResultObj resultWithName:@"eigth"],nil];

    _filteredResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[_unfilteredResults count]];

    [_acSearchTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [_searchDsplyCntrl setActive:YES animated:YES];
    [_searchDsplyCntrl.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [_searchDsplyCntrl setActive:NO animated:YES];
    [_searchDsplyCntrl.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

> [A search bar displayed in a navigation bar cannot have a scope bar.](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchDisplayController/displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar)
>
> IMPORTANT The system raises an exception if you set the showsScopeBar
>   property to YES in a search bar that is displayed in a navigation bar.

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == _searchDsplyCntrl.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [_filteredResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [_unfilteredResults count];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Create a new Candy Object
    ResultObj *result = nil;

    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Candy object from the appropriate array
    if (tableView == _searchDsplyCntrl.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        result = [_filteredResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
    else
    {
        result = [_unfilteredResults objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[result name]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark Content Filtering

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.

    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
    [_filteredResults removeAllObjects];

    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
    NSArray *tempArray = [_unfilteredResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


    /*
    if(![scope isEqualToString:@"All"]) {
        // Further filter the array with the scope
        NSPredicate *scopePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.category contains[c] %@",scope];
        tempArray = [tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:scopePredicate];
    }
    */

    _filteredResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[_searchDsplyCntrl.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[_searchDsplyCntrl.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    // Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[_searchDsplyCntrl.searchBar text] scope:
     [[_searchDsplyCntrl.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```